# Are there words for the reverse of some grammatical relations?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> Henry saw the exhausted soldier.

In this sentence, the subject of *saw* is "Henry". The modifier of *soldier* is "exhausted".

Are there words for the reverse of these relations and others?

You could use the reverse of "subject" in:

> The **_____** of *Henry* is "saw".

Comment: The _predicate_ is what isn't the subject, so the predicate of that sentence is _saw the exhausted soldier_. But it would be odd to call that _the predicate of "saw"_;  and I don't know a term for just "saw" in relation to "Henry".

Comment: There are a vast number of grammatical relations and very few of them have opposites. _Opposite_ itself is a hard term to define in grammar. _Main_ and _subordinate_ are opposites, but what's the opposite of a relative clause?